# Exhaustive search finds nothing: Android emulator loads only emergency call app

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have have been using the Android emulator both and the command-line and in Intellij for some weeks running ApiDemos and my own apps with no problems.
Now, without any exceptions or messages to indicate the reason why the emulator will only run the emergency call app and nothing more.

Is this a bug? If so, how do I create an issue for the Android SDK dev?
I'm cautious to load any .apk now into my handset to see if the condition is the same.

Particulars follow:

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04
- Android SDK: 4.1 (ICS).
- JDK: 1.7.x

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a stupid answer, but are you sure you didn't set a PIN code on the lock screen? This will load the PIN entry screen whenever you load the emulator but still allow you to make emergency calls.

You have to set a PIN on Android ICS when you save new security certificates, which caught me out.

Comment: Yes -- the keypad looks like a phone dialer because it says "emergency dialer" but in fact it's asking for a PIN code for unlocking the device.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use 2 GB of RAM o avoid that problem in your android emulator.